# how do i seperate the json arrays so that they have differant variables

Tags: android, json

hey there everyone i have this json code

```
[{"page_no":"1","btn_one":"choice one p1","btn_two":"choice two p1","btn_three":"choice three p1","btn_four":"choice four p1","btn_five":"choice five p1","page":"this is the first page"},{"page_no":"2","btn_one":"choice 1 p2","btn_two":"choice 2 p2","btn_three":"choice 3 p2","btn_four":"choice 4 p2","btn_five":"choice 5 p2","page":"this is the second page"}]
```

that i need to display in a text view and the 5 btns, but i dont know how to seperate both the json arrays so that i can display one then the other

it displays in the textview

```
this is the first pagethis is the second page
```

the same happens with the buttons. i need it to display in the text view

```
this is the first page
```

then when you click a button it should refresh and display

```
this is the second page
```

here is my full edited code

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {



//used to download
String result = "";
InputStream is = null;


String[] pageIndex = null;
String[] pageOne = null;
String[] choiceOne = null;
String[] choiceTwo = null;
String[] choiceThree = null;
String[] choiceFour = null;
String[] choiceFive = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    returnJson();


//end of onCreate()    
}

    public void returnJson(){
final TextView page = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
final Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
final   Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
final Button btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);

    try{
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/textures_story_one.php");

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        page.setText("error3");
    }

    try{


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"), 8);                      
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e) {
        page.setText("error2");         
        }
    try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

    for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){

            pageIndex[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("page_no"); 
            pageOne[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("page"); 
            choiceOne[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("btn_one");
            choiceTwo[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("btn_two");  
            choiceThree[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("btn_three");
            choiceFour[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("btn_four"); 
            choiceFive[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("btn_five");

    }
    page.setText(pageOne[0]);
    btn1.setText(choiceOne[0]);
    btn2.setText(choiceTwo[0]);
    btn3.setText(choiceThree[0]);
    btn4.setText(choiceFour[0]);
    btn5.setText(choiceFive[0]);

    }
catch(JSONException e) {
   // page.setText("error1");
}

// set the onClickListener for the button you want with the following code
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        page.setText(pageOne[1]);
        btn1.setText(choiceOne[1]);
        btn2.setText(choiceTwo[1]);
        btn3.setText(choiceThree[1]);
        btn4.setText(choiceFour[1]);
        btn5.setText(choiceFive[1]);
    }
});

return;


//end of returnJson()   
}


//end of class    
}
```

now it throws several errors, im not to worried about the buttons atm but am quite happy for a bit more help on exactly how to display

```
this is the first page
```

in the text view

Comment: so basicly i need to know how to split the two json objects

Comment: is my json right aswell or would it be better with getting a result of 2 json objects instead of 2 json arrays

Answer (score 0):

That code is only concatenating both pages/buttons in the same String objects. You should use separate variables, or an array, and change the page and each button's text when the user clicks the button.

Using your code, it could be something like this:

```
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"), 8);                      
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();

}catch(Exception e) {
    page.setText("error2");         
    }

try{
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

    for(int i = 0;i<jArray.length();i++){

            pageIndex[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("page_no"); 
            pageOne[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("page"); 
            choiceOne[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("btn_one");
            choiceTwo[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("btn_two");  
            choiceThree[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("btn_three");
            choiceFour[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("btn_four"); 
            choiceFive[i] = jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("btn_five");

    }
    page.setText(pageOne[0]);
    btn1.setText(choiceOne[0]);
    btn2.setText(choiceTwo[0]);
    btn3.setText(choiceThree[0]);
    btn4.setText(choiceFour[0]);
    btn5.setText(choiceFive[0]);

}
catch(JSONException e) {
    page.setText("error1");
}

// set the onClickListener for the button you want with the following code
YOURBUTTON.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        page.setText(pageOne[1]);
        btn1.setText(choiceOne[1]);
        btn2.setText(choiceTwo[1]);
        btn3.setText(choiceThree[1]);
        btn4.setText(choiceFour[1]);
        btn5.setText(choiceFive[1]);
    }
});

return;
```

Note that `pageOne`, `choiceOne`, `choiceTwo`, `choiceThree`, `choiceFour` and `choiceFive` should now be String arrays instead of Strings.

Comment: that has given me several errors of    The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String on pageIndex[i]

Comment: String pageIndex = "";
 String pageOne = "";
 String choiceOne = "";
 String choiceTwo = "";
 String choiceThree = "";
 String choiceFour = "";
 String choiceFive = ""; is my declarations should they change from string to array, if so how do you declare array?

Comment: goncalossilva i added your code and fix the strings to string[] but now it crashes onstartup with several errors, im not worried about the onClickListener rather just being about to seperate the json? would it be better to have the json as two objects one for page one and one for page two? atm im happy to have btn1 call page two and set the buttons to choice one p2.... does my question make sense, iv only been learning for a short time

Comment: can you still help me please?

Comment: The only thing `onClickListener`'s `onClick` method does is to attach a click listener to that `View` (a Button is a `View`) so that some code runs when it is "clicked".